# A linkage of preposition

Tags: prepositions

> 5.2.3 Signals and interrupts
> Functions shall be implemented such that they may be interrupted at any time by a signal,
> or may be called by a signal handler, **or both, with no alteration to earlier, but still active,
> invocations’ control flow (after the interruption), function return values, or objects with
> automatic storage duration**. All such objects shall be maintained outside the function
> image (the instructions that compose the executable representation of a function) on a
> per-invocation basis.

This is a fragment of ANSI C99 standard.
It's hard to read first sentence including highlighted part("or both ~ storage duration").
In particular, I don't know nouns with no preposition(invocations' control folw, function return values, or objects with automatic storage duration) are influenced by what previous one. If you parse that sentence, I'll be really appreciated.

Comment: Your function may be called again *while it's still executing in response to a previous call*. I'm not sure how ***to be interrupted*** differs from ***to be called [again]***, but I'm guessing that just means execution of your function may be suspended / interrupted by calls to ***other*** "interrupt service routines" as well as by multiple calls to the specific function under consideration here.

Comment: But I don't fully understand what it means. According to my knowledge of *English*, it's saying that making a second or subsequent call to the interrupt service routine ***must not*** affect the ongoing execution of some previous call to that routine. But according to my knowledge of programming in general, I can't see any reason why the currently-executing routine shouldn't be aware of and react to the fact that it will be / has been called *again* (so maybe the first invocation might want to quit early because what it's doing is or will be "redundant").

Comment: The *entire* sentence is structurally quite complex, so that could be a pretty long breakdown. Is there some *specific* aspect of it that's causing you difficulty?

Comment: No, I think I have more grasp now because you give me the new viewpoint. It helped me. I don't fully understand the clause too. Maybe the last thing to fully understand it is learning CS more. I can't understand that sentence because of a lack of CS knowledge, not English now. Thank you!

Comment: The more I look at it, the more I think that spec is just plain ***wrong***. What they ***want*** it to mean is that multiple calls shouldn't "destabilise" any already-running instance of the service routine (which should be coded as "re-entrant"). But it's ***not*** unreasonable for such a routine to deliberately change what it's doing in response to becoming aware (through a sentinel flag, or whatever) that it's liable to be called again immediately the current execution ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is quite a sentence.  I'm a native speaker and a computer programmer and it took me a little while to understand what it meant.

Let me paraphrase.

You call function foo().

You then call function foo() again, while the first call is still running.

The second function being called should, in no way, affect what happens in the first call.

Comment: In turn, `or both`, `but still active`, and `function return values` are optional. The sentence without them makes sense although they are meaningful part of it. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps break it down like this

> Functions shall be implemented such that they may be interrupted at any time by a signal, or may be called by a signal handler, or both,

so they must be written like that, but what are the consequences

> with no alteration to earlier, but still active, invocations’ control flow (after the interruption),

So when they come back after the interruption they have not altered any of those things

> function return values,

Or altered them

> or objects with automatic storage duration.

> All such objects

The ones referred to at the end of the last sentence

> shall be maintained outside the function image (the instructions that compose the executable representation of a function) on a per-invocation basis.

I cannot help feeling that this could have been written more simply.